# Writing a compiler: how to get simple templates to work?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a language with a very C++-like syntax. The lexer and parser are in place and produce the correct AST. For the largest part the backend is also done.

The basic system the compiler uses to create types is very simple: all types are considered built-in and all instances are global. So there's just a simple map which matches a types name to a method that creates a *Variable* which is basically a generic type like boost::any. Another map with the variable's name as key and the Variable as value serves as the global scope:

```
std::map< std::string, std::function< Variable() > typeList;

  //register some types
typeList[ "X" ] = Variable::Create<X>;
typeList[ "Y" ] = CreateInstanceOfY;
....
```

When the compiler gets the AST node for an initialization like `X myVar;` it basically does

```
std::map< std::string, Variable > globalScope;
globalScope[ "myVar" ] = typeList[ "X" ]();
```

When myVar is used later on it can be accessed by simple type dispatching like

```
X& x = myVar.GetReference<X>();
```

Now I would like to extend this a bit and use simple templates. Suppose there is a type "array" which is implemented using a vector. I could register everything like

```
typeList[ "array<X>" ] = Variable::Create< std::vector< X > >;
```

but that is not quite managable as it would have to be repeated for all combinations. Ideally I'd need functionality allowing to write something like this:

```
typeList.CreateTemplateVariable( "array", "X" )
```

which would then create a Variable instance which internally holds an std::vector< X >. I tried hard but cannot figure out how to do this. Maybe I just started the wrong way with the simple type mapping and is that the reason I cannot get my head around it.

So the question is simple: is it possible to do this? And how?

Comment: when you make c++ code from AST, it IS already a compiler anyway.

Comment: A little nitpick about terminology: A compiler translates code from one format to another. An interpreter executes some code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for pointing that out.. I'm really not good with terminology.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I got your problem right, but if you have M parametric types (`vector<>`, `list<>`, ...) and N simple types (`int`, `double`, ...), you would need M*N actual implementations if you want to support all combinations. All these implementations have to be known at compile time (or in principle you might invoke C++ compiler on-the-fly). Do you actually want this?

A workaround could be to use non-typed containers instead. For example, `vector<Object*>` storing pointers that can be subsequently converted to the required type, for example with a `dynamic_cast`. This way you would only need M implementations for parametric types, and can resolve "array" to `vector`, and "X" to `X` independently.

Comment: you are right about the M*N, however it would be better to have some dynamic system that also supports, or can be extended to, nested templates and multiple template parameters. I am going to see if the non-typed approach gets me somewhere though, looks interesting.

Comment: @stijn, you can still have everything typed in your language, have templates and whatever else. The problem arises when you try to map types from your language into C++ one-to-one, such as you are trying to do for "array<X>" --> vector<X>. You don't have to do it, though - anything that looks typed in your language does not have to be typed in the implementation, as soon as your compiler does type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the way you do template-like types is as you describe, but instead of creating all possible combinations ahead of time, you create them on demand.  So you might have a `getType` routine like:

```
std::function< Variable() > getType(std::string name) {
    auto rv = typeList[name];
    if (rv) return rv;
    auto template_start = name.find('<');
    if (template_start != string::npos) {
        auto template_end = name.rfind('>');
        std::string arg = name.substr(template_start+1, template_end);
        std::string base = name.substr(0, template_start);
        typeList[name] = rv = InstantiateTemplate(base, arg);
        return rv; }
    throw UnknownTypeError(name);
}
```

This gets called for any type referred to in the program, creating the needed template instantiations on demand.

Comment: thanks for the input, but the largest part of your function is actually what the parser does already; moreover it does it recursively so my parser handles nested templates with unlimited arguments like array< array< A< int, bool, double > > > and creates an AST node called TypeSpecifier for it. My question is how to write the `InstantiateTemplate` functionality, ie how to transform the TypeSpecifier into an actual instance of a type.